# Google Script App: Why can't I send ajax requests to my web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script

I'm sorry if this question is duplicated but I've couldn't find a solution for this.

I need your help with Google Script Web App, please. I built a very simple Web App for tests using Google Script App but I can't send parameters to it using Jquery Ajax...

I've tried to use a simple $.post() but it shows me this error:

[image: Error trying a simple Ajax request]

Then I added dataType = "jsonp" (that's what I'm using currently) and now it shows this error:

[image: Error trying a request with dataType = 'jsonp']

Sometimes it shows this error as well:

[image: Anathor error using dataType = 'jsonp']

Parameters works greatly when I send it via GET directly from the Browser Url:

[image]

Here's the documentation explaining that it can receive HTTP GET and POST requests: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Here's my Web App that simply shows the parameters received: [Web App](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxndq6GNDw9FE_0y-POSFBFK3jMypF-CFfjNAWGDY1WzoIrfuA1/exec) and its [Source Code](https://script.google.com/d/1VDYlbcyK-6XIbjG8EOpne4yitsyQ2DzTUgIq-0WCQSYJSMhk1guU7I5w/edit?usp=sharing)

And finally, here's my page that sends the request to my Wep App... (I also used a web app to do that but I've tried from [my server](http://rejanecnc.tk/outros/test.html) too). My [Ajax sender web app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyXQGahOilVriq-1Yf_Teww7uHgl4jEOi-X6Is-hyLgXl_2dKfw/exec) and its [Source Code](https://script.google.com/d/1C9Kj--juTn2IfjwVyfRVVyCEIyVfqoPu7TGxEnDZZ5Nk8mQWxUR_SFTX/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I was gonna ask this whole question when my only mistake is that I was using HtmlService to write my response in the server. That was why this error:

[image]

I should use ContentService and set MimeType to text or Javascript